# MVC Post Request - Max no. of objects in IEnumerable<T> binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an Controller Action as follows for posting Form Data (Just testing binding atm, comments left in to give you an idea of things I've tried):

```
[HttpPost]
//[RequestFormLimits(BufferBodyLengthLimit = 2097152000)]
//[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessF([FromForm] IEnumerable<FBillingPostDTO> bills)
{
    return Json("Success");
}
```

This Post Action is called via AJAX with the following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("ProcessF","Billing")",
        type: "POST",
        //contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "bills": promiseArray }
    }).done(function () {
        location.href = "/F/Manage/"
    })
```

The data binds to the IEnumerable, but only if the submitted collection is of 256 objects or less.  Any more than this and the binding returns null with 0 entries.

I thought this may be a `maxAllowedContentLength` issue, but after padding the data, it seems to be the number of objects in the submitted array that causes it to return null.

Before I go back to the start and refactor it to avoid this limitation, is there a setting controlling this value?  IEnumerable of length 256 seems a bit too much of a coincidence, especially when the ContentLength doesn't cause the problem (i.e. 256 elements @ 36Kb is accepted, but over 256 elements @ 35Kb is rejected)

The application is .Net Core 3.1 running locally on IIS express (Debugging).

Comment: Wow, that's odd. Are you using the new JSON parser or have you set it to use NewtonsoftJson?

Comment: Using the standard one, I've been trying to avoid NewtonSoft since .net core included it's own.  Gonna leave it for a bit and see if something shows up here, otherwise I guess I'm just going to have to stringify the data and parse it out on the other side :( Sucks when you try to do stuff the "proper" way and it refuses to work

Comment: Check in fiddler or in request parameter, is is actually passing more than 256 from frontend?

Comment: Check webconfig for  maxRequestLength. This can be the issue in post request.

Comment: It will bind if the collection is 256 or less. Have also tried the maxRequestLength in web.config with no joy.  I am going to try a test DTO with only 1 key value pair (currently has 4) to get a definitive on contentLength vs collection size.  Give me 10 minutes and will update

Comment: Gah. It IS a contentLength issue.  Managed to bind 535 with a single key value pair. 
I wonder why all my web.config, startup.cs and annotations did nothing to override that? I'll go muck around with those until it works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really need to open my eyes more, somehow I missed this in the call stack when debugging , under `this.Request.Form`:

`"Form value count limit 1024 exceeded"`

All it required was adding `[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = xxx)]` annotation to the Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = 10000)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessF([FromForm] List<FBillingPostDTO> bills)
    {
        return Json("Success");
    }
```

So 256 objects of 4 Key Value Pairs = 1024 Values which is the max allowed by default.  I need to improve my googling, as this is news to me haha.

Comment: Great solution. In my case, when the number was exceeded, no model binding was taking place at all and the data was being received as null - very hard to debug. Thanks!