# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : post model binding complex collection back to controller instantiates vm but without data

Tags: collections, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, poco, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to post back a complex collection (POCOs) to my controller.  The array created by `serializeArray()` looks good to me (but maybe it is not).

I tried conforming my code in this project to code that works in an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC & EF 6 project I have. Something has changed since then. Can't figure out what I am missing.

Here's my current version of the Ajax call:

```
$('#btnCreate').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("CreatePL", "Reports")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ glassDemands: $('#plTarget').serializeArray() }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                success: function(data) {
           },
           error: function(xhr) {
           }
    });
});
```

Here's a screenshot of the first several lines of data it creates:

[image]

This screenshot shows the action in the controller with result from post:

[image]

Here are the three classes that make up the view. Microsoft documentation states that

> POCOs that do not have parameterless constructors can't be bound.

Code:

```
public class GlassDemand
{
    public GlassDemand()
    {
        Boxes = new HashSet<Box>();
    }

    public string bunk { get; set; }
    public int sequence { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }
    public string elevation { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Glass")]
    public string glasstag { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Needed")]
    public int glassqty { get; set; }
    // total quantity selected from boxes. should be the sum of all related boxitem.usedqty
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Sel Qty")]
    public int pickedqty { get; set; }

    [NotMapped] 
    public ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class Box
{
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BoxItem> BoxItems { get; set; }
    public int MatchedTo { get; set; }

    public Box()
    {
        BoxItems = new HashSet<BoxItem>();
    }
}

public class BoxItem
{
    public BoxItem()
    {
    }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
    public decimal Qty { get; set; }
    public int BoxId { get; set; }

    public int UsedById { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}")]
    public decimal UsedQty { get; set; }
    // remaining = Qty (box quantity) - sum(UsedQty from all instances)
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}" )]
    public decimal Remaining { get; set; }
    // navigations
    public virtual Box Box { get; set; }
}
```

And the view model that is sent to the view when it is launched.

```
public class PickListDemandVM
{
    public IEnumerable<GlassDemand> GlassDemands { get; set; }

    public PickListDemandVM()
    {
        GlassDemands = new List<GlassDemand>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.serializeArray()` is used to post `application/x-www-url-formencoded` content type data to backend.Change your code like below:

```
$('#btnCreate').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("CreatePL", "Reports")',
        data:  $('#plTarget').serializeArray() ,
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
        }
    });
});
```

Remove `[FromBody]` in Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePL(List<GlassDemand> glassDemands)
```

Comment: although I didn't see your answer until after I had come to the same conclusion, your answer does address part of what the issues were.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all the nuances of model bindings.  One thing is for sure though, you have to have keys on all tables being posted.  With proper keys in place, I can use a view model or a `List<>` parameter in my controller action.  From MS documentation, using a view model is the preferred method.

My POCOs didn't have keys. I ended up using a counter while I built my data on the highest level table, GlassDemand.  Then built increasingly more complex keys for each descendent.

I added the following to my classes to hold the values that are dynamically being created for their respective tables.

```
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
```

I added this line to my display templates

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

This is the first two rows look like that is being posted back to the controller now.

[image]

My dataset was also too large. I had to add the following attribute to the controller action.  [Thanks to DAustin's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64224334/3147517)

```
    [RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = 10000)]
```

the final jquery that posts back the data:

```
        $('#btnCreate').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("CreatePL", "Reports")',
                data: $('#plTarget').serializeArray(),
                success: function(data) {

                },
                error: function(xhr) {

                }
            });
        });
```

the final action in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [RequestFormLimits(ValueCountLimit = 10000)]
    public ActionResult CreatePL(PickListDemandVM vm)
    {
```